Azure Trusted Signing, ClickOnce manifest
I have tried to find a solution regarding ClickOnce and Azure Trusted Signing, however I just can't find a solution.
Is it in anyway possible to sign the manifest of ClickOnce using Trusted Signing? Mage seems to be out of the question, but is it possible in other ways? Has anybody found a solution?
I have seen this post from this summer, work around with Velopac, but honestly I would rather not introduce our customers for this change.

You can leverage this: https://dlemstra.github.io/github-stories/2024/signing-nuget-packages-with-trusted-signing/
2 caveats:

This is not directly MSFT supported solution
You need to manage the cert anytime app is updated to pin the trust on the leaf certificate since Trusted Signing certificates have short validity.


This seem to work, I just don't know what you mean with point 2. It shouldn't pose a problem that certificate is short lived, only 3 days. As it will not render the ClickOnce app unusable after expiry.
